# How to force yum to update only to exact minor OS version

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I have a default AWS image with the version CentOS 6.7. If I run

```
yum update
```

I am getting CentOS 6.9.

Is there any way to force yum to update only to version 6.8 and not 6.9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Follow these steps:

- Find a mirror that is closer to you using: http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os.
- Replace 6.9 with 6.8, e.g., the URL would look like:http://mirrors.gigenet.com/centos/6.8/os/x86_64/.
- Create a yum repo file in `/etc/yum.repos.d`. Let's name the file `User-Stepped.repo`.
- Content of the file would look like the following:

  ```
  ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/User-Stepped.repo
  [User_Stepped]
  name=A stepped repo - CentOS 6.8
  baseurl=http://mirrors.gigenet.com/centos/6.8/os/x86_64/
  gpgcheck=1
  gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
  ```
- Execute the following command to update to `CentOS 6.8`

  ```
  ~]# yum clean all
  ~]# yum --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=User_Stepped update
  ```

Use the same name in `--enablerepo` as you used inside the square brackets of the User-Stepped.repo file.